# Where do I find my Gramps data on a Mac or other Unix based file system?

Tags: gramps, product-support

If I am running gramps, and I load a gedcom file in - where does it put the data file? If I load more than one, where are they?

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

By default, Gramps uses `~/.gramps/grampsdb/`, as Duncan says, but if this setting has changed you can find out the new directory by going to the Edit menu, then "Preferences", then second tab ("family tree").

Answer (score 4):

Gramps creates a hidden directory in your home directory called .gramps containing all the user-specific data. There is a directory in that directory called grampsdb (eg /Users/yourname/.gramps/grampsdb) that contains all your data stored in individual directories for each family tree.

Since this is a hidden directory, it won't be observable with normal finder settings but can be looked at using terminal.

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac, you'll find the hidden Gramps directory here:

/Users/yourid/Library/Application Support/gramps/gramps34

for Gramps version 3.4.